# Protection from water pressure surge

Tags: plumbing, water, copper

Is there a way to prevent damage to your pipes from a water pressure spike from the city supply? In my case, sweated and threaded copper, no PTC.

It seems like a large water hammer arrester anywhere in the system would do that, but I also have never heard of something like that.

Comment: A surge arresting device may slightly dampen the problem but not protect an extended pressure spike that can damage fixtures.

Answer (score 2):

although hammering will does not damage pipes, it can and will damage toilet and sink angle stop valves. I live in Arizona with 80-90 psi water pressure, and had to replace all. Water pressure surge absorbers cost about $35 plus installation, and is worth every penny spent. If you live in an area with high water pressure, my advice is to install one.

Comment: I have seen water hammer rub through pipes that were not anchored well enough.

Answer (score 1):

Decent copper plumbing in the home could easily handle pressure spikes double or triple the normal water pressure entering a home, so there would be no need for a pressure arrester

Answer (score 1):

I have seen more damage to home faucets than to the plumbing. When pressures get above 90 it puts a lot of wear on the seals. To protect things adding a regulator for potable water is used and setting the pressure ~60+ range keeps the system spikes from causing problems.